# How do I show a user an image on a fragment using Picasso(or any other ways possible really)?

Tags: java, android, picasso

Besides having my fragment created, it's empty, all I want that fragment to do is to show the user an image.

```
public class CenterFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_center, container, false);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Android Studio and don't really mind if I get redirected to tutorials.

Comment: `Picasso.get().load(URL).into(imageView);`

For more, [see this](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: @SavaDimitrijević Where do I write that line? It always shows me "Cannot resolve symbol 'image'.

Comment: First of all you need to make an object of View and assign inflater value to it, then return that view at the end. But before all that make an object of ImageView and use findViewById to initialize it from XML and then use the line above to load image with Piccaso.